# docker-compose.yml without an image property

Tags: docker, docker-compose

compose.yml found on github to create a LAMP environment.
The script works fine, but I can't understand how as it doesn't state an image property for apache or mysql, please can you let me know how it knows what image to use.

```
version: "3"

services:
  webserver:
    build:
      context: ./bin/${PHPVERSION}
    container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-${PHPVERSION}"
    restart: "always"
    ports:
      - "${HOST_MACHINE_UNSECURE_HOST_PORT}:80"
      - "${HOST_MACHINE_SECURE_HOST_PORT}:443"
    links:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT-./www}:/var/www/html:rw
      - ${PHP_INI-./config/php/php.ini}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${SSL_DIR-./config/ssl}:/etc/apache2/ssl/
      - ${VHOSTS_DIR-./config/vhosts}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LOG_DIR-./logs/apache2}:/var/log/apache2
      - ${XDEBUG_LOG_DIR-./logs/xdebug}:/var/log/xdebug
    environment:
      APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: ${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT-/var/www/html}
      PMA_PORT: ${HOST_MACHINE_PMA_PORT}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT: ${HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: "client_host=host.docker.internal remote_port=${XDEBUG_PORT}"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
  database:
    build:
      context: "./bin/${DATABASE}"
    container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-${DATABASE}"
    restart: "always"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:${HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    volumes:
      - ${MYSQL_INITDB_DIR-./config/initdb}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR-./data/mysql}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR-./logs/mysql}:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-phpmyadmin"
    links:
      - database
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: ${UPLOAD_LIMIT}
      MEMORY_LIMIT: ${MEMORY_LIMIT}
    ports:
      - "${HOST_MACHINE_PMA_PORT}:80"
      - "${HOST_MACHINE_PMA_SECURE_PORT}:443"
    volumes:
      - /sessions
      - ${PHP_INI-./config/php/php.ini}:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-phpmyadmin.ini
  redis:
    container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-redis"
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:${HOST_MACHINE_REDIS_PORT}:6379"
```

Comment: Those _build:_ sections state image building instead of usage of a ready to use image. Take a look at the path which is stated at _context_ fields, most probably you'll see there dockerfiles.

Comment: It builds local image based on `build` key (using Dockerfile in specified directory) instead of pulling from registry and then uses it. It's one of the most important patterns in compose, in fact: you can build your containers and configure them together with third-party images with single command.

Comment: @SUTerliakov and Monsieur Merso - thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image is for predefined images that can be found on dockerhub.
The build property defines the location of images that you might've created or modified that are on your local computer that need to built.